# Limit the amount of dynamic content blocks into an email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, content

I have an email that will pull in content blocks according to category selection in a table within a DE. The user could have up to 11 categories selections associated to there User ID in the DE. I will have dynamic content blocks build for all 11, but I want to limit it to only pull in 3 per user into the email.

How would I limit the amount of content blocks being pull into the email to just 3?

Comment: You could consider ditching Dynamic Content in favour of AMPScript, using the LookupOrderedRows() function. Limit the number of records returned to three in the function.

Comment: Thanks Macca, I would usually use AMPscript but the DE doesn't have all the content in to populate the email, we are coding that manually into the various content blocks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can base the email on a template, you can limit the amount and type of blocks in a particular position in the slot definition of the template:

Put the following div into your mastertemplate and you will create a "limited" slot which only allows three dynamic content blocks at this position.

```
<div data-type="slot" data-key="xyzasdgsadgsadgsadgsdag" 
data-max-blocks="3" 
data-allowed-blocks="dynamicblock" 
data-label="At this position you can insert up to three blocks of type dynamic content"></div>
```

The options that I know of are (last checked about a year ago):

```
freeformblock
textblock
htmlblock
imageblock
abtestblock
dynamicblock
pirecommendationblock
socialshareblock
socialfollowblock
buttonblock
externalcontentblock
codesnippetblock
referenceblock
imagecarouselblock
enhanceddynamicblock
```

Comment: I have 11 content blocks with different categories containing content, will the solution above just limit the template to only allow me to pull in three of the 11 blocks? All users would have different selected various categories, not all the same.

Comment: This slot will allow three dynamic content blocks of any kind at its position.